# I can't get all values from each textboxes

Tags: javascript

I am trying to display the inputs in the textboxes into the p1 elements.

i am able to get the value of whatever it is in the first textbox. However, I cannot get the values from other textboxes. I have the same statements for displaying the values which I have entered in the textboxes. But it only displays the value of the"firstname".

Everything, except the "firstname", stays NaN after I click the submit button.

```
 <body>
 <form>
    First name:     <input type="text" id="firstname"> <br/>
    Middle initial: <input type ="text" id="middleinitial"> <br/>
    Last name:      <input type ="text" id="lastname"> <br/>
    Age:            <input type ="text" id="age"> <br/>
    Address:        <input type ="text" id="address"> <br/><br/>
    SEAT RESERVATION <br/>
    Row:            <input type ="text" id="row"> <br/>
    Column:         <input type ="text" id="col"> <br/>
    <input type="button" onclick="display_reservation_information()"><br/>
 </form>

 Full name: <p1 id="last_name_display">NaN</p1>, <p1 
 id="first_name_display">NaN</p1> <p1 id="middle_inital_display">NaN</p1>  
 <br/>
    Age: <p1 id="age_display">NaN</p1> <br/>
    Address: <p1 id="address_display">NaN</p1> <br/>
    Seat reserved: Row <p1 id="row_display">NaN</p1>, Column <p1 
    id="column_display">NaN</p1> <br/>

<script>

     function display_reservation_information(){
        document.getElementById("first_name_display").innerHTML = 
        document.getElementById("firstname").value;
        document.getElementById("middle_initial_display").innerHTML = 
        document.getElementById("middleinitial").value;
        document.getElementById("last_name_display").innerHTML = 
        document.getElementById("lastname").value;
    }
 </script>
 </body>
```

Edited: I added the elements which I would put the values into. I forgot to add them but I have them in the first place and it still not working.

Comment: None of what you showed indicates such error. Provide a [mcve] that does.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Oh yes I noticed. But I havent touched that part yet. I cant display the values of the lastname and the middleinitial which are properly put.

Comment: @LGSon I am not sure it has an error. I just had the same code for the lastname and middleinitial and I wonder with the firstname. I dont know why only firstname works.

Comment: @AaronAncheta could create a jsfiddle with a code sample? Could you please also elaborate a bit more on what are you trying to accomplish exactly? Like that, we'll be able to assist you properly.

Comment: I have copy-pasted your code in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/giuseppedeponte/pen/ZEzZoPd) and it seems to work. I have only added the missing "display" elements to the markup

Comment: @AaronAncheta check my answer & let me know if it helps!

Comment: @AaronAncheta Well, the main issue here is that the posted code work as is (if added the `div`), so there's nothing we can do, unless you provide a [mcve]

Comment: @AaronAncheta have you check my answer? Does it helps?

Comment: @giuseppedeponte How did it work for you?

Comment: @ManuelAbascal yes I have :)

Comment: @AaronAncheta I just copy-pasted your code and added the three target display elements : 
`<span id="first_name_display"></span>
<span id="middle_initial_display"></span>
<span id="last_name_display"></span>`
When I click on the button, the three spans are populated with the value for the respective input field

Comment: @AaronAncheta Also, I updated my [codepen](https://codepen.io/giuseppedeponte/pen/ZEzZoPd) with your new markup and it doesn't work because you have `p1` elements instead of `p` and a typo in one of your ids `<p id="middle_inital_display">`. Since your function throws after setting the first input value, the other values are skipped.

Comment: BTW, there are definitely better ways to implement this.

Answer (score -1):

look at that code and try it yourself.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="inp" id="name" />
<input type="text" class="inp" id="surname" />
<input type="text" class="inp" id="message" />
<button>take my data</button>
```

JS:

```
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.inp');
const btn = document.querySelector('button');

btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    inputs.forEach(inp => {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.textContent = inp.value;
    document.body.appendChild(div);
  })
})
```

Comment: "_Try this.._" + code dump is a bad answer. An answer should have an explanation, so users doesn't have to parse code and hopefully find out what you did.

Comment: Sorry Porithe but I couldnt understand how you used the commands because I only just start with Javascript. I was hoping to use those that I have in my code because my problem was they were not working to ALL textboxes even when there is ONE textbox that is.